# Is there a way to change the icon(s) or text from the Apple Startup Manager on the new Macbook PRO 2019?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, catalina, dual-boot

I have a MacbookPro16,1 (2019) configured in dual-boot (MacOS Catalina 10.15.3 and Windows 10). I would like to change the icons presented on the Mac Startup Manager and, if possible, the text as well. Even if I choose a volume name when creating the partitions before the Bootcamp installation, the "Windows" label automatically appears like in the screenshot below :
[image]

Maybe it is worth mentioning that FileVault2 is enabled on the MacOS side, and Bitlocker on the Windows side. But I can start from a clean install and make those modifications before enabling both.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks that actually make sense, will do it right away.

Answer (score 2):

Strangely, I think it's possible to easily change the icon on macOS in the `Get Info` box of the hard drive you've selected in Finder. Although you may have to disable SIP to do so. Additional steps may be required if you are on macOS Catalina 10.15, since the system files are now protected on a separate disk volume. I'm not sure about these steps as I'm still on macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

To change the icon, select the hard drive and press `cmd`+`i` keys and select the icon in the top left corner and drag or paste a new icon. Pasting/dragging the new icon must be in icns format I believe. You can convert a png to icns format by changing the extension of the file from `.png` to `.icns`.

Note, I've only done this with my macOS hard drive and not my Windows partition. It may not be possible with Windows partition. I've attached the Get Info screenshot and a screenshot of the Startup Disk Manager when booting my Mac.

[image]
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: What happens if you mount the EFI partition and do the same thing? Would this change the Windows icon?

Comment: Converting a Portable Network Graphic file (`.png`) to a Icon Set file (`.icns`) probably at least requires using a command such as `iconutil`. First, you probably want create a set of scaled `.png` files by using a command such as `sips`.  There are third party workflows which can be downloaded that will automate the conversion. For example, see [here](https://filipmolcik.com/convert-png-to-icns-right-click-converter/). Once installed, you just have to right click on the `.png` in the Finder and select `PNG to ICNS`. The new `icon.icns` file will be put on your desktop.

Comment: That's weird, i managed to change the Windows icon by mounting the EFI partition like you suggested (so problem solved thanks to you AGAIN) but it will not work for the volume Macintosh HD. Disabled SIP - mounted the system partition to be writtable and tried with Get-info box no luck.