# Edit Icons for MacOs Startup Manager (Windows, Linux & Macos)

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, windows, partition, unix

After successfully installed Linux and Windows along with macOS High Sierra on my Macbook Pro 2013 13" with help from Mr. David Anderson (a great contributor here). Now I wonder how to change the icons for my Windows (installed on a separate internal SSD) and give MacOs Partition Icon of MacOs so that the startup manager will be beautifully labeled and easy to see. Thank you for the help in advance!

Current startup manager conditions:
[image]

My diskutil list:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
   1:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                250.1 GB   disk0s1

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *240.1 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         151.8 GB   disk1s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data                         7.9 GB     disk1s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data                         79.9 GB    disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +151.8 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk1s2
   1:                APFS Volume MacOsX                  14.6 GB    disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 24.5 MB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                512.1 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      4.3 GB     disk2s4
```

Comment: Have you seen this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/382288/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-icons-or-text-from-the-apple-startup-manager-on-t

Answer (score 1):

### For MacOS

The `.VolumeIcon.icns` file should be placed in the root folder of the APFS Volume named `Preboot`. Follow the steps given below.

1. Enter the command below to mount the `Preboot` volume.

   ```
   diskutil mount disk2s2
   ```
2. Use the Finder to navigate to the root folder of the `Preboot` volume. In the sidebar of a Finder window, highlight the `MacOsX` volume. If this volume is not shown, then make sure `Hard disks` is checked off under Sidebar in Finder Preferences. Next, if the `Volumes` folder does not appear, then press the key combination <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to show hidden files. Navigate to `MacOsX > Volumes > Preboot`. This is the root folder of `Preboot` volume.
3. Use the Finder to copy the `.icns` file to the root of the `PreBoot` volume.
4. Rename the `.icns` file to `.VolumeIcon.icns`.
5. Press the key combination <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, so hidden files will not appear in the Finder window.
6. Enter the command below to unmount the `Preboot` volume.

   ```
   diskutil unmount disk2s2
   ```

### For Windows

You have a BIOS booting Windows. This is the correct installation of Windows for your model/year Mac. I suppose the Windows logo icon should go in the Windows partition. However, doing so should not work, because the firmware cannot read NTFS formatted volumes. So there probably is no way to change the icon displayed in the Startup Manager, when you have a BIOS booting Windows.